# @font-face is not working for CSS with correct format, generation, and directory path

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have jumped through all kinds of pages trying to figure out why my code is not working. I see this is a popular question but I am sure that I have covered all my bases:

1. I am sure I have the correct path (See below)
2. I have generated the right files using transfonter
3. The demo page that came with transfonter works thus the font should work
4. I am using Chrome
5. I call font-family: 'Sevastopol_Interface';

CSS Code and Directory Tree:

[image: Directory Tree]

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Sevastopol_Interface';
    src: url('\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.eot');
    src: url('\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.woff') format('woff'),
        url('\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.svg#Sevastopol-Interface') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Edit: Changed directories. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the issue:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Sevastopol_Interface";
  src: url("Fonts//Sevastopol-Interface//Sevastopol-Interface.ttf");
}
```

The issue is that my path was not quite right. Backslashes are indeed correct but I needed two of them instead of one as I am on a windows machine. Not something like linux where you would only need one. Thanks to @Syed Muhammad Moiz and @Kusal Darshana for leading me to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the backslash to normal slash (/) in your path of the font. Like this,

```
src: url('Style-Sheets/Fonts/Sevastopol-Interface/Sevastopol-Interface.eot');
```

You can find out more about this from here. [HTML File Paths - W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) .

*All the best.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that did not work either. I even tried double slashes. The stylesheet transfonter generated also used '\' instead of '/' but neither work..

Answer (score 1):

**OK, I have used @font-face in my CSS like this:**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Vibes";
  src: url("/src/fonts/GreatVibes-Regular.ttf");
}
```

Go to google-fonts and add the required fonts by clicking `+` then download those fonts by clicking download on the bottom right of the page your fonts`.ttf` files will be downloaded, now just add the `.ttf file` to your `@font-face` src as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Sevastopol_Interface';
    src: url('Style-Sheets\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.eot');
    src: url('Style-Sheets\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: url('Style-Sheets\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.woff2') format('woff2');
    src: url('Style-Sheets\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.woff') format('woff');
    src: url('Style-Sheets\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.ttf') format('truetype');
    src: url('Style-Sheets\Fonts\Sevastopol-Interface\Sevastopol-Interface.svg#Sevastopol-Interface') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Note : This is only a guess. See also [CSS @font-face Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)

Comment: Even with the updated directories, it fails :(